# React - toggle visibility of an element not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to toggle the visibility of an menu in a React app. I have tried by setting the state property that I change on click. And then I am checking the objects state to toggle visibility. This is the code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        'menuOpen': false,
    }
}

openMenu() {
    var newState = !this.state.menuOpen;
    this.setState({
        'menuOpen': newState
    });
}

var menuList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
          <div className={styles.menuList}>
            <ul>
              <li>Link</li>
              <li>Link</li>
              <li>Link</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
    }
});

render() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.menu}><span className={styles.menuIcon} onClick={this.openMenu.bind(this)} />
            {this.state.menuOpen ? <menuList /> : null}
        </div>
    );
}
```

I get an error:

```
> in ./src/components/post/index.js Module build failed: SyntaxError:
> Unexpected token (31:8)
> 
>      }   
>     var menuList = React.createClass({
>             ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try uppercase for the first letter MenuList

Comment: Why is your menuList component defined within a variable in your other component's class? I'm pretty sure only methods are allowed inside ES6 class declarations, not arbitrary `var` declarations. Try moving your `menuList` component into its own class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Changes:

**1.** Don't define a `class` inside another `class`, if you want a separate class then define outside within same file. We can create multiple `classes` in same file.

**2.** Use either `es6` or `es5` way of creating a react component, you are using `es6` way for outer and `es5` for inner.

**3.** Since name starts with small letters are treated as HTML elements, so its a rule that all React components must start with a upper case letter, so instead of `menuList` use `MenuList`.

**4.** `var menuList = .....` is not a valid syntax, check more details about class [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Write the code like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        'menuOpen': false,
    }
}

openMenu() {
    var newState = !this.state.menuOpen;
    this.setState({
        'menuOpen': newState
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.menu}><span className={styles.menuIcon} onClick={this.openMenu.bind(this)} />
            {this.state.menuOpen ? <MenuList /> : null}
        </div>
    )
}

class MenuList extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.menuList}>
                <ul>
                    <li>Link</li>
                    <li>Link</li>
                    <li>Link</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```